# Do URLs corresponding to IP address get cached in browsers?

Tags: caching, dns, ip, url-routing

Scenario is : We had some   x.x.x.x Ip address corresponding to URL www.website.com for our website URL .We changed it so some y.y.y.y ip address corresponding to same URL www.website.com. 
But a problem occured and some of our customers were not able to reach our server(website) using that URL.

```
How new ip addresses get published across internet?     
How much time does it normally take,to complete this process. 
Can it be possible that some browsers due to cached IP address,don't ask to DSN to reslove URL to IP ?
Do browers cache "IP TO URL resolving" ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS records are cached both in the browser and in every DNS server along the way to the authoritative server.  The length of time is specified by TTL ("time to live"), and can be set explicitly, with granularity down to the individual record.  The default for TTL, AFAIK, is both implementation-dependent and configurable, but seldom, if ever, longer than a day.

In order for a browser or other client to see a DNS update, every TTL along the recursion route from the authoritative name server must have expired, in "downstream" order from the authoritative name server.  In practice, this can take as much as a couple of days, but usually less than one.